# UnsatisfiedLinkError ,while using JEP

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jepp

I am trying to use JEP to communicate with a python module from Java.
I am using intellij on MacOS catalina
I have done the following

1. Used pip to install JEP, installation directory is `/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jep/`
2. Add the path as an environment variable in .zshrc file

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jep/'
3. Added the path in jvm params like this
   [image]
4. I am getting the error(from intellij) in this line
   `Jep jep = new Jep();`

   **The error that I am getting is this**

   `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jep/libjep.jnilib:dlopen(/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jep/libjep.jnilib,  1): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.8.dylib`
5. If I package the code in jar ,and run it as java -jar somejar.jar
   It gives an error

   `Error: Unable to initialize main class Application Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jep/JepException`

6.My build.gradle file looks like this

```
dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/black.ninia/jep
    implementation group: 'black.ninia', name: 'jep', version: '3.8.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}
```

Comment: How do you run the app in IDE? Please add this information. In Run/Debug Configuration there are **VM Options** field where you need to add the `-Djava.library.path` option. You do not need to add it in the IDE .vmoptions file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue with VM options , but even after specifying it I am getting an error

Comment: For the 1st error: `Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.8.dylib` try to specify the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` into **Environment variables** box in IDE run configuration and make sure the path you set - contains needed library. See also https://github.com/ninia/jep/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-fix-unsatisfied-link-error-no-jep-in-javalibrarypath

Answer (score 0):

If it helps the original poster, or anyone else who comes across this post:

If you have followed all of the advice [here](https://github.com/ninia/jep/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-fix-unsatisfied-link-error-no-jep-in-javalibrarypath) and still get the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, make sure your python `jep` install is the same version as the version listed in your pom.xml